# Windows Server Service Bus 1.0

Tags: azureservicebus, servicebus, server-farm

I am using Windows Server service bus 1.0. It was working fine up til now, but the Certificate of the farm has been expired.

I am no longer able to use service bus.

I would like to renew same certificate but I cannot find any useful help on the Google.

How can I find out at how to renew same farm's certificate?

Comment: Yep.  Hindsight, you didn't pay attention to the certs that Microsoft auto-voodoo-created for you.  I feel for ya.

Answer (score 1):

> Could anyone please help to find out, at how to renew same farm's certificate?

You could find that answer from this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/service-bus-archive/jj712784(v=azure.100)#how-to-renew-an-expired-certificate). To replace an active Service Bus for Windows Server farm certificate with a new certificate, do the following:

> 1. Call the Stop-SBFarm cmdlet to stop all of the Service Bus for Windows Server services on all hosts. Execute this cmdlet on one of the farm nodes.
> 2. Install a new certificate on all Service Bus for Windows Server machines.
> 3. Call the Set-SBCertificate cmdlet with the following parameters. Run this cmdlet on one of the farm machines.
>
>    - FarmCertificateThumbprint: Thumbprint of the new farm certificate.
> 4. Call the Update-SBHost cmdlet on all farm nodes.
> 5. Call the Start-SBFarm cmdlet on one of the farm nodes.

Comment: Thanks for you reply Tom. I am not able to run Service Bus powershell command in the powershell. When I try to stop  farm. There comes an error that says powershell module is missing related to ServiceBus. I did not get this error before, It came after certificate was expired. Do you have any idea how to solve this.

Comment: Please refer to this [link](https://danieljudele.wordpress.com/2016/11/04/load-servicebus-for-windows-server-module-in-powershell/) to import powershell module.

Comment: I used that tutorial, but it is giving me an error on below line [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(“PSModulePath”,Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable(“PSModulePath”,”Machine”)) 
and the error is "Missing Expression , unexpected token". Do you know why is it so

Comment: I have solved powershell problem with the help of your link, but i am unable to run service bus command on powershell for example "stop-sbfarm" command. It says to me that certificate requested with the thumbprint not found in the store LocalMachine\My. I can see expired certificate in the store with same thumbprint. I do not know why it is saying so. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Sorry for no idea about that. I recommand that you could post another SO thread to add the detail information then you could get the more help from all communities.